# Novel about a jacket self-filling money

Tags: story-identification

I remember a very short novel I read when I was in class about 10 years ago (2005ish). The story was basically about a man who found (or bought?) a jacket, and every day when he put his hand in the jacket he finds more and more money, but at the same time on the news he sees people dying, and their death is linked to the amount of money he gets (I remember an old woman dying, if it can be any help).

In the end, I'm pretty sure he tries to burn the jacket, but it is too late and something happen but I don't remember what.

I'm sory if it is a bit confused, I was quite young and don't remember all the details.

One more thing, It was in French when I first read it.

I would really love to find it, if you got any question I'll be very happy to try helping

Comment: I'll add the remaining details later. The story was originally published in Italian.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Le Veston Ensorcelé

Now, keep in mind that my French is *terrible*. So forgive the (possibly) awkward translations I am about to give. But could this be "Le Veston Ensorcelé," or "The Enchanted Blazer"?

> Par habitude je ne mets rien dans la poche droite de mon veston, mes
>   papiers je les place dans la poche gauche. Ce qui explique pourquoi ce
>   n’est que deux heures plus tard, au bureau, en glissant par hasard ma
>   main dans la poche droite, que je m’aperçus qu’il y avait un papier
>   dedans. Peut–être la note au tailleur ? Non. C’était un billet de dix
>   mille lires.

Or

> I usually do not put anything in the right pocket of my jacket; my
>   papers I place in the left pocket. Which is why it is not until two
>   hours later, in the office, slipping by chance my hand in the right
>   pocket, I realized that there was a paper within. Perhaps the note to the
>   tailor? No. It was a ten thousand lire note.

The owner of the blazer realizes that the source of the money is always the misfortune of others.

> Je savais que chaque fois que je soutirais l’argent de mon veston, il
>   se produisait dans le monde quelque chose d’abject et de douloureux.
>   Mais c’était toujours une concordance vague, n’était pas étayée par
>   des preuves logiques. En attendant, à chacun de mes encaissements, ma
>   conscience se dégradait, devenait de plus en plus vile. Et le tailleur
>   ? Je lui téléphonai pour demander sa note mais personne ne répondait.
>   Via Ferrara on me dit qu’il avait émigré, il était à l’étranger, on ne
>   savait pas où. Tout conspirait pour me démontrer que, sans le savoir,
>   j’avais fait un pacte avec le démon.

Which is to say:

> I knew that every time I took money from my jacket, there occurred
>   in the world something nefarious and painful. But it was always a
>   vague agreement, was not supported by logical proofs. Meanwhile, with each
>   of my receipts [of money], my conscience was deteriorating, was more vile. 
>   And the tailor? I phoned him to ask his note but no one answered. Via
>   Ferrara told me that he had emigrated, he was abroad, no one knew
>   where. Everything conspired to show me that, without knowing it, I had
>   made a pact with the daemon.

There *is* an elderly woman (a sexagenarian), and the protagonist *does* try to burn the jacket.

> Mais à la dernière lueur des flammes, derrière moi — à deux ou trois mètres aurait-on dit —, une voix humaine retentit : « Trop tard, trop tard ! » Terrorisé je me retournai d'un mouvement brusque comme si un serpent m'avait piqué. Mais il n'y avait personne en vue. J'explorai tout alentour sautant d'une roche à l'autre, pour débusquer le maudit qui me jouait ce tour. Rien. Il n'y avait que des pierres.

That is:

> But at the last light of the flames behind me - two or three meters you might say - a human voice rang out: "Too late, too late!" Terrified, I turned suddenly as if a snake had bitten me. But there was no one in sight. I surveyed the area around me, jumping from one rock to another to flush out the cursed one playing a game with me. Nothing. There were only stones.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate that's it! I'm really grateful I wanted it soo bad! thanks again!

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer You're welcome! Do you speak Italian or Spanish, as well as French? One of the featured questions could benefit if you do.

Comment: Nope, I would gladly help but I'm not speaking Italian or Spanish, I'll give a try with some of my collegues who do, who know we might find something!